# Custom Action: copy my template, not see Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, custom-actions, visual-studio-2015

I was create "**SharePoint 2013 - Empty project**" in Visual Studio and add module "**CustomRibbonActionModule**", then add **HTML-Page** (Module Name="CustomRibbonActionModule", File Path="CustomRibbonActionModule\HTMLPage1.html" Url="CustomRibbonActionModule/HTMLPage1.html" ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction Description="Copy html"
         Id="68275191-272b-4c59-a9ee-ee736f76f2e5"
         Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
         Title="Copy template">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab.Clipboard.Controls._children">
      <Button
          Id="copyHtmlSelection"
          Alt="Copy html"
          Sequence="100"
          Command="CustomRibbonButton_CopyHtml_Command"
          Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png"
          Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png"
          LabelText="Copy template"
          TemplateAlias="o1" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomRibbonButton_CopyHtml_Command"
      CommandAction="javascript:var spans = $('#BD');
                                  spans.text('');
                                  function copy() {
                                      var target = document.getElementById('BD');
                                      var range, select;
                                      if (document.createRange) {
                                          range = document.createRange();
                                          range.selectNode(target)
                                          select = window.getSelection();
                                          select.removeAllRanges();
                                          select.addRange(range);
                                          document.execCommand('copy');
                                          select.removeAllRanges();
                                      } else {
                                          range = document.body.createTextRange();
                                          range.moveToElementText(target);
                                          range.select();
                                          document.execCommand('copy');
                                      }
                                  }" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
<Module Name="CustomRibbonActionModule">
<File Path="CustomRibbonActionModule\HTMLPage1.html" Url="CustomRibbonActionModule/HTMLPage1.html" />
</Module>
</Elements>
```

My HTML-Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="BD">
<tr class="blank_row"><td></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Function Requested:</td><td></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#FE9A2E' style="width: 300px;height: 22px;font-size: 17px">JOB RELATED INFORMATION</td><td></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Title</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'><span id="JB"></span></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Department</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'><span id="DP"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Manager</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'><span id="MA"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Notes:</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Web Page:</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="blank_row"><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#FE9A2E' style="width: 300px;height: 22px;font-size: 17px">Leaver information</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Leaving date:</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Account deletion date:</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Mail forwarding required Yes/No:</td><td bgcolor='#81BEF7'></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">File permissions rescinded Yes/No:</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">Removed from All DL's:</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#A5DF00' style="text-align: right;">User machine retained Yes/No:</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

My Project not see HTML-Page, how is to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add mapped folder **Layouts** (create folder: scripts), then create file js and add xml new **CustomAction**:

```
<CustomAction
  ScriptSrc="scripts/script.js"
  Location="ScriptLink"
  Sequence="100">
<UrlAction Url="~sites/test/SitePages/Template.aspx" />
</CustomAction>
```